# Read global variable Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm getting an access Token through a Service, declare a global variable and am trying to use the received Token in another function or page.
But it's always coming back to me "UNDEFINED", what am I doing wrong?

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
public globalToken: string;

constructor(...){}

getToken() {

var request = require('request');

return request.post({
  uri: "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Language": "en_US",
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  auth: {
    'user': 'xxxxxxx',
    'pass': 'xxxxxxx',
    // 'sendImmediately': false
  },
  form: {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
  }
}, function (error, response, body) {
  let json = JSON.parse(body);
  // console.log('token', JSON.stringify(json.access_token));
  this.globalToken = json.access_token;
  console.log('tokentoken', this.globalToken);


});


}
```

but when I try to access "globalToken" in another function return 'undefined'.

```
testToken() {
this.globalToken;
console.log('testtoken', this.globalToken);  //  I CAN SEE THE TOKEN
}
```

Comment: You need to use arrow function in your call back. checkout my response.

Comment: Yes, it is stated. "public globalToken: string".

Comment: Yep, I have updated my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use arrow function in your call back as **this** refers to the function's context when you use the function syntaxe to declare one:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
public globalToken: string;

constructor(...){}

getToken() {

var request = require('request');

return request.post({
  uri: "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Language": "en_US",
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  auth: {
    'user': 'xxxxxxx',
    'pass': 'xxxxxxx',
    // 'sendImmediately': false
  },
  form: {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
  }
},(error, response, body) => {
  let json = JSON.parse(body);
  // console.log('token', JSON.stringify(json.access_token));
  this.globalToken = json.access_token;
  console.log('tokentoken', this.globalToken);
});

}
```